# Jquery .load() not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, load

Hi everyone i am new here and this is my first question.

I have a problem with some JS code in IE 11.

this is the problem:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#jqueryFuction').load('ping?sessioneWeb=${requestScope.sessioneWeb}').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

</script>
<div id="jqueryFuction">

 </div>
```

this code send a request in my server that control if there is some JS code to push on the client.

in my server (i use Spring MVC) i write that code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ping")
    @ResponseBody public String ping(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@ModelAttribute("sessioneWeb")String sessioneWeb,@ModelAttribute("item")ClientWom3Form item)
    {
        UserContainer userContainer = (UserContainer) request.getSession().getAttribute(sessioneWeb);

        if(userContainer != null && Util.isNotNull(userContainer.getFuctionReadyJQ()))
        {
            String valore = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"+userContainer.getFuctionReadyJQ()+"</script>";
            userContainer.setFuctionReadyJQ("");
            return valore;
        }
        else
            return "";
    }
```

with this code i can push the JS code in my

this code works fine in Chrome and FF, but in IE doesn't. i can't reach the server and i don't know why.

I see that the browser pass to the load every second but it doesn't reach the server and the console doesn't show any error.

I use jquery-1.10.2.min.js

can anyone helps me please?

thank you to all for attention and help

Comment: First thing to test is to remove your ajax request from the interval and see if IE handles it. Anyway, making an ajax call each second is just wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE is famous for caching requests like this.  I'd suggest you add a unique argument to the URL to bust the caching.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    $('#jqueryFuction').load('ping?sessioneWeb=${requestScope.sessioneWeb}&timestamp=' + now).fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

</script>
```

Also, the `fadeIn()` won't work unless `#jqueryFuction` is set to hidden before you do the `.load()`.

I'd also argue that you really don't want to be doing an ajax call every second.  Some ajax calls will take more than a second to even process and if you have a lot of viewers, this will bring your server to its knees.  Think about a much longer time interval or a more efficient way to let your server tell you when there's something new (like websockets).

Comment: I'd suggest instead to use a timeout a re-set a new timeout on each ajax complete :)

Comment: Thank you very much! this solution works fine! and thank you again for teach me some thing that i didn't kwon, really thank you. I try to implement a websocket to resolve my problem

Comment: @Littlered - since it looks like you may be new to StackOverflow, do you know that if you get an answer that solves your problem, you should click the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That indicates to the other readers that this is the answer that solved your problem.  It also earns both you and the person who provided the answer with some reputation points which can earn you some more privileges on StackOverflow.